# White border around list elements

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list inside a div element that specifies a background image. All the li elements that I have in it have small white borders around them. I have tried setting the padding, margin, borders and background properties but nothing seems to get rid of them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Casey, can you post the relevant css and html code? Does your background image have a 1px white border in it?

Comment: Or at least a link? Does it happen in all browsers?

Comment: I have checked it with Firefox 3.5.2 and IE 6 and it appears in both. I looked at it using Firebug and nothing I tried got rid of the borders. It almost looks like a padding issue. The css is quite large but I will try and post the hopefully relevant portions.

Comment: here is the html:
<div id="warning_messages">
    Before you get started<br/>
    <ul>
        <li>Please make sure to read the <em>Important Information</em></li>
        <li>To complete this application you must be an Authorized Officer of the Business</li>
        <li>Be prepared to provide your Federal Tax ID</li>
        <li>All fields marked with an asterisk (*) are required</li>
        <li>If the information is incomplete, we may not be able to approve the application</li>
    </ul>
       </div>

Comment: Some of the css
#warning_messages { background-color: #f2f4ac; background-image: url(../images/warning_bg.gif); background-repeat: repeat; height: auto; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; border: dashed 1px #dbcc0e; }

#warning_messages span { color: #696621; }

#warning_messages img {margin-top: 5px}

Answer (score 0):

That is very strange.

I'd ensure that no background color is set on the ul.

Can you inspect using firebug?